# Python: Checking Characters in String

Tags: python-3.x

So I keep trying to make this work but I do not know where it is going wrong. The text file contains:

```
III

@@@
```

This is what I have so far. I do not see what is wrong.

```
CHARACTERS = ["I","@"]
def checkFile():
    inFile = open("random.txt","r")
    text = inFile.read()
    inFile.close()
    x = True
    for line in text:
       line.strip()
       for i in range(len(line)):
           if line[i] in CHARACTERS:
               x = True
           else:
               x = False
               return False
    return True
def main():
    check = checkFile()
    if check == False:
       sys.exit()
    elif check == True:
       print("bye")
       sys.exit()
main()
```

It should print "bye" because all the characters in the file are in the list; however it just exits without the print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `txt` file contains two lines of text, one on top of each other, it also includes a hidden `'\n'`. To change that add `'\n'` to `CHARACTERS`, or copy the following code:

```
CHARACTERS = ["I","@", "\n"]
def checkFile():
    inFile = open("random.txt","r")
    text = inFile.read()
    inFile.close()
    x = True
    for line in text:
       line.strip()
       for i in range(len(line)):
           if line[i] in CHARACTERS:
               x = True
           else:
               x = False
               return False
    return True
def main():
    check = checkFile()
    if check == False:
       sys.exit()
    elif check == True:
       print("bye")
       sys.exit()
main()
```

**EDIT:** I created a `txt` file called `test.txt` and I pasted your text into it. I then ran the following code:

```
>>> file = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
>>> file
'III\n\n@@@\n'
>>>
```

Because there are two lines in between, it has teo `'\n'`s. You can get rid of this by either adding `'\n'` to `CHARACTERS`, or by **calling `text = inFile.read().split()`** *with the `split()`*

When you call `line.strip()`, you are not assigning `line.strip()` to any value. Thus, the `'\n'` remains 'unstripped', so to speak. Instead, call `line = line.strip()`.

Comment: I do not want the newline that is why i am using line.strip to get rid of the new lines so it shouldnt make a difference

Comment: in actuality the text file contains"III\n@@@\n" even when I do the split function and fix the line.strip() it does not work properly. Why will it not work when it is stripping the line of the \n and then asking to check for the characters in that line. strip should get rid of the \n but it is not

Comment: When I run the code fixing the `line = line.strip()`, the output is `bye`. Try checking your code again.

Comment: are you using your other fixes as well?